# Lambda Max and Max and Max

Tags: c#, lambda

Quick and probably easy Lambda question:

I have a restaurant with reviews.
I want to query for the one with the:

- Max(AverageRating)
- And the Max(ReviewCount)
- And the Max(NewestReviewDate)
- And the Min(DistanceAway)

Something like this:

```
var _Result = AllRestaurants
    .Max(x => x.AverageRating)
    .AndMax(x => x.ReviewCount)
    .AndMax(x => x.NewestReviewDate)
    .AndMin(x => x.DistanceAway);
```

Now, I know that is pseudo code. But it describes it perfectly!

Of course, in multiple statements, this is simple.

Just wondering if this is possible in one statement without killing the readability.

Thank you in advance. I know some of you love the query questions!

Comment: The question is unclear.  Each of the five queries you've mentioned can return a different restaurant.  It does not make sense to combine the queries in this way.

Comment: And what should result contain?  A single restaurant that has the best combination of all of the criteria, or 4 different restaurants, one for each criteria?  Note that you should explain in depth, because each option would still need to be clarified in more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have multiple maxes or mins, that doesn't make sense.
You'll need some kind of heuristic like:

```
   .Max(x => x.AverageRating * x.ReviewCount - x.DaysSinceLastReview - x.DistanceAway)
```

Comment: If this is generally what you mean, you'll also most likely want to specify weights for each criteria.

Comment: Exactly.  You'll need weights to tune it to return the answer you want.

Comment: @SteveWortham Both are legitimate possibilities, which is why I simply asked the OP rather than assuming he means one or the other.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "and".

Comment: It's ambiguous in this context.

Comment: +1. Searching for  extremums in multidimensional space is interesting task, but some simplification like this makes it possible for us, mere mortals :).

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this would do?

```
var bestRestaurant = AllRestaurants
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.AverageRating)
    .ThenByDescending(r => r.ReviewCount)
    .ThenByDescending(r => r.NewestReviewCount)
    .ThenBy(r => r.DistanceAway)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

You'd need to change the order of the statements to reflect which is the most important.

Comment: You might want to use `FirstOrDefault` instead to avoid a possible `InvalidOperationException` when the sequence is empty.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to having some weighted heuristic is to order by AverageRating, then ReviewCount, then ...

Something like this should work:

```
var _Result = AllRestaurants
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.AverageRating)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.ReviewCount)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.NewestReviewDate)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.DistanceAway);
    // using *Descending so you get the higer-valued ones first
```

Comment: Similar to [Richard's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10986444/284240) apart from that you prefer further away restaurants ;)

Comment: Maybe I like to take nice long drives?  Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, I think the best approach is going to be writing individual statements as you mention...

```
var HighestRating = AllRestaurants.Max(x => x.AverageRating);
var HighestReviewCount = AllRestaurants.Max(x => x.ReviewCount);
var LatestReviewDate = AllRestaurants.Max(x => x.NewestReviewDate);
var ShortestDistanceAway = AllRestaurants.Min(x => x.DistanceAway);
```

Retrieving various maxes and mins from a single Linq query would get pretty messy and I'm not sure there'd be any advantage with efficiency, either.

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this...

```
List<RestaurantRecord> _Restaurants;

public RestaurantRecord Best()
{
    return _Restaurants.Where(
               x =>
                   x.AverageRating >= _BestRating &&
                   x.ReviewCount >= _MinReviews &&
                   x.Distance <= _MaxDistance)
                       .GetFirstOrDefault();
}
```

That being said, using a lambda in this case will have maintainability consequences down the road.  It would be a good idea to refactor this, such that if other criteria appear in the future (e.g.: smartphone access?  Cuisine type?), your app can be more easily modified to adapt to those.

On that note, a slightly better implementation might be something like:

```
public RestaurantRecord Best()
{
    IQueryable temp = _Restaurants.Clone();

    temp = temp.Where( x => x.AverageRating >= _BestRating );
    temp = temp.Where( x => x.ReviewCount >= _MinReviews );
    // ...snip...

    return temp.GetFirstOrDefault();
}
```

I hope this sets you on the right track. :)